# Can't open id_rsa.pub file on MacOS Monterey via cli that prompts to `No application knows how to open, Code=-10814`

Tags: macos, command-line-interface

Couldn't file the resolution within the forum, therefore, resolved it by myself.

**ISSUE**

macOS Monterey couldn't open `id_rsa.pub` file via cli giving an error below:

`No application knows how to open URL file:///Users/romansaverins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "kLSApplicationNotFoundErr: E.g. no application claims the file" UserInfo={_LSLine=1489, _LSFunction=runEvaluator}).`

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLUTION**

1. `$ open ~/.ssh/`
2. Open the file manually
3. Choose the `TextEdit` app
4. Close the file.
5. Open manually again (App should not be asked)

Now `id_rsa.pub` could be opened via CLI.

- `$ open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Happy days...

Comment: This worked for me, in my case I had told VSCode to not request an extension to open .pub files which made it unable to be opened via CLI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle it using CLI only and for any extension, you can use `open -a appName filePath` where appName could be TextEdit and filePath your relative or absolute filePath.